# Pythonic way to find max and min of an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, slice

What I have:

```
vec=[{'max': 23.425, 'date': u'2017-07-18', 'ismax': False, 'ismin': False, 'min': 14.615}, 
     {'max': 23.83, 'date': u'2017-07-19', 'ismax': False, 'ismin': False, 'min': 14.765}, 
     {'max': 24.07, 'date': u'2017-07-20', 'ismax': False, 'ismin': False, 'min': 14.985}]
```

Now I want to find the overall minimum and maximum; i've tried doing this:

```
mini=min(vec[:]['min'])
maxi=max(vec[:]['max'])
```

But it says:

> Type error indexes must be integers not str

I knew that colon stands for 'cycle across all the indices' so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `min` and `max` function with a `key` argument:

```
In [966]: max(vec, key=lambda x: x['max'])['max']
Out[966]: 24.07

In [967]: min(vec, key=lambda x: x['min'])['min']
Out[967]: 14.615
```

You can speed this up a bit using `operator.itemgetter`.

Using these functions with a key returns the entire sub-dict containing the max/min, so you'd need to use indexing to retrieve just the value you want.

---

#### Timings:

Setup: `vec = [{ 'max' : random.randint(1, 1000), 'min' : random.randint(1, 1000)}  for x in range(100000)]`

```
# @RemcoGerlich's solution
In [990]: %timeit min(v['min'] for v in vec)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop

# proposed in this post
In [991]: %timeit min(vec, key=operator.itemgetter('min'))['min']
100 loops, best of 3: 9.19 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

`vec[:]` just makes a copy of the list. So `vec[:]['min']` tries to lookup `'min'` in the copy, but that doesn't work as list indices must be integers.

Good job for a generator expression:

```
mini = min(v['min'] for v in vec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply make use of the `key` param in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#min)/[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#max) function

```
min(vec, key=lambda x: x['min'])
max(vec, key=lambda x: x['max'])
```

the `min()` one gives:

```
{'ismin': False, 'min': 14.615, 'date': '2017-07-18', 'ismax': False, 'max': 23.425}
```

Click the above link to python doc for detailed info.

Comment: This exact solution has already been posted. Why post it again?